# Issue using "CalculatedFields" for Excel in Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, pivot-table, calculated-field

I am attempting to write a PowerShell script to automate generating a report with a pivot table. I have done this before, however this time I need to use a calculated field to get the percent difference between the sum of two fields in the pivot table. I created a macro of the steps taken when doing this in Excel and am having issues emulating it in PowerShell. When I try and invoke the calculatedFields property, passing three arguments as the macro does, I get an error stating "*Cannot find an overload for "calculatedFields" and the argument count: "2"*" I have tried playing with it, unsuccessfully. Any tips would be appreciated.
Thank You!

Excel Pivot Table, with third field being calculated field:
[Excel Pivot Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HA7Hq.png)

Macro of calculatedField:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").CalculatedFields.Add "percent", _
    "= (DepotScan) /orderid2", True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").PivotFields("percent").Orientation = _
    xlDataField
Range("D5").Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").PivotFields("Sum of percent")
    .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
End With
```

Powershell Script(calculated field starts at line 170 or $pivotField4):

```
$source = $ws1.range("A:L")
$ws2 = $wb.worksheets.add()
$dest = $ws2.range("A5")
$ws2.name = "Main"
$pivotTable = $wb.PivotCaches().create(1,$source,7)
$pivotTable.createpivottable("R5C1","Pivot") | out-null
$dest.select()

$pivotField = $ws2.PivotTables("Pivot").PivotFields("PickupReadyDate")
$pivotField.orientation = 1
$pivotField.position = 1
$ws2.PivotTables("Pivot").PivotFields("PickupReadyDate").AutoSort(2,'PickupReadyDate')
$ws2.PivotTables("Pivot").CompactLayoutRowHeader = "PickupDate"

$pivotField1 = $ws2.PivotTables("Pivot").PivotFields("DepotScan") 
$pivotField1.orientation = 4
$pivotField1.caption = "Total Scans"

$pivotField2 = $ws2.PivotTables("Pivot").PivotFields("orderid2")
$pivotField2.orientation = 4
$pivotField2.caption = "Total Orders"

$pivotField3 = $ws2.PivotTables("Pivot").PivotFields("ScanExempt") 
$pivotField3.orientation = 3 
$pivotField3.position = 1
$pivotField3.caption = "Exempt"

$pivotField4 = $ws2.PivotTables("Pivot")
$pivotField4.calculatedFields('ScanExempt','= (DepotScan) /orderid2', "True") 
$pivotField4.orientation = 4
$pivotField4.caption = "Scan %"
```

Edit: See below for error code when I change it to $pivotField4.calculatedFields.add(...)

Also of note when I pass two arguments it states it cannot find an overload, however if I pass just one argument it throws an "invalid Index error".

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSMethod] does not contain a method named 'add'.
At C:\Users\jthompson\Desktop\Powershell\DailyScanningReport.ps1:177 char:1
+ $pivotField4.calculatedFields.add('ScanExempt','= (DepotScan) /orderi ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Comment: Please read and follow [ask], and  [edit] your question to share a [mcve].  Adding code instead of screenshots is easier for everyone. [Do not upload images of code or of textual program output when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Instead, copy and paste the text…

Comment: ```CalculatedFields``` is a **property**, not a method. In your VBA version you call ```ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").CalculatedFields.Add ...``` but in your PowerShell version you do ```$pivotField4.calculatedFields(...)```. Try ```$pivotField4.calculatedFields.Add(...)``` instead. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable.calculatedfields and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.calculatedfields

Comment: I tried that as well and it threw an error. I will edit above to include the error info. Also of note when I pass two arguments it states it cannot find an overload, however if I pass just one argument it throws an "invalid Index error".

Comment: Ok, it looks like ```CalculatedFields``` is a method as well rather than a property - try ```$pivotField4.calculatedFields().Add(...)``` - with ```()``` immediately after ```calculatedFields```.

Comment: Still no luck. When I do $pivotfield4 | getmember, it shows me the claculated fields method like so: CalculatedFields...Method...CalculatedFields CalculatedFields ()  . When I set it like so $pivotField4 = $ws2.PivotTables("Pivot").calculatedfields() and look up the members it shows me there is an add method...   Add... Method ...PivotField Add (string, string, Variant)